# jQuery drag-and-drop DIV selection with images and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using the jQuery tableDnD plugin to make a drag-and-drop list out of a table displaying a list of images for the user to rearrange. The plugin uses an ID on the  tag of the formatting table to rearrange the cells.

When I drag and drop specifically clicking on a spot inside the table cell with no images/content, it works fine. However, when I click on the image (or inside a div containing text) withgin the table cell and try to drag+drop, the text/image gets selected and the rearrange script is not triggered. Neither blocking the select function with css or javascript has worked - any idea?

Example tableDnD code: http://tablednd.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/index.html

Sample rows from the table in question:

```
     <table id='imagetable'><tr id='1'><td><img src='images/6/PICT0001.JPG' width='100' class='uploadedThumb'><div class='imgInfo' onselectstart='return false;' ondragstart='return false;'>images/6/PICT0001.JPG<br><a href='admin.php?do=deleteImg&id=6&img=images%2F6%2FPICT0001.JPG' style='font-size: 9px;'>[Delete Image]</a></div><input type='text' name='6' value='' size=2 DISABLED></td>

</tr><tr id='2'><td><img src='images/6/PICT0006.JPG' width='100' class='uploadedThumb'><div class='imgInfo' onselectstart='return false;' ondragstart='return false;'>images/6/PICT0006.JPG<br><a href='admin.php?do=deleteImg&id=6&img=images%2F6%2FPICT0006.JPG' style='font-size: 9px;'>[Delete Image]</a></div><input type='text' name='6' value='' size=2 DISABLED></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use jQuery use dom-drag it's much better and more functional.

Add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/domdrag/dom-drag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Drag.init(document.getElementById("exampleid")); //sets the id to look for to make object draggable
</script>
```

Sorry I misunderstood the question :(